# How to implement completely custom interactive View Controller transitions without subclassing UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I've been looking to implement my own interactive custom view controller transition without using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition since I want full control of how my views will look at various stages of the transition. Unfortunately I cant find anything online, and all the examples use UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.

**What i've done:** 
-setup my animator to implement the UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning protocol
-implemented

```
- (void)startInteractiveTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
```

**Where i'm lost**
-I need to update the state of my views while the user is interacting with a pan gesture recognizer, but after poking into the UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol and noticing the updateInteractiveTransition method, i cant figure out where I would implement this last missing piece.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885844/1161906). He does it in [SCPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.h](https://github.com/stringcode86/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithCABasicAnimation/blob/master/InteractiveTransition/SCPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.h) and [.m](https://github.com/stringcode86/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransitionWithCABasicAnimation/blob/master/InteractiveTransition/SCPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.m).