# UIView spring animations and UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm trying to write interactive animations between 2 view controllers that involves pinching in a collection view cell to (interactively) reveal the next view controller. When I implemented this without interactive animations, it looked great with spring animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:]
```

However, after adding in the interactive logic with `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` and a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, I realized that the spring animation call doesn't work as well. If I pinch halfway and let go, it suddenly jumps to the last keyframe of my animation, and doesn't give me the smooth animation that I got when using the normal `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868376/uipercentdriveninteractivetransition-with-cabasicanimation)

Comment: Try  `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` as options